# Access data (create a list) through a loop - iteration over fieldname (import from Matlab into Python)

Tags: loops, matlab, import, iteration

I want to create a list from a matlab struc as follows:

```
#Import
mat2=sio.loadmat('TestData.mat',squeeze_me=True,struct_as_record=False)

#Solution without a loop
v1 = mat['pyDMD'].v1)
.
.
.
v17 = mat['pyDMD'].v2)

data = [v1, . . ., v17]

#Loop over fieldnames
data = []
fieldnames = []
fieldnames.append(mat['pyDMD']._fieldnames)

for t in range(len(fieldnames)):
   data.append(mat['pyDMD'].fieldnames(t))
```

v1..v17 are a 100x100 arrays of float64. How can I iterate over fieldnames - last line. My approach is obviously not correct.

Comment: Also try using `data.extend()` rather than `data.append()`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple:

```
for field in mat2['pyDMD']._fieldnames:
    snapshot = getattr(mat2['pyDMD'], field)
    data.append(np.transpose(snapshot))
```

Comment: Make sure to indent your code correctly :)